# What does the following jQuery code mean?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery. What does the following code mean? Especially the first part.

```
$(".locale-en-us", $iframe).append($('script').attr('type', "text/javascript").attr('src', "https://mytestbox/testsite/test.js"));
```

Answer (score 1):

it is going to add script tag to your element having class locale-en-us which is present in $iframe element

```
    <div class="locale-en-us">
        <script src="https://mytestbox/testsite/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code will find the element with class name "locale-en-us" and then Add an Iframe element.
In Iframe element add the script with set type="text/javascript" and src="https://mytestbox/testsite/test.js".

Comment: I am not sure what syntax '**$iframe**' is. It seems a bracket is missing. And according to here (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) this should be the searching context.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first part means:
select the elements whose class is 'locale-en-us' from the jQuery variety 'iframe'.

The rest codes can be understood easily:
add js file!